# bazel exclude transitive dependencies

Tags: bazel, transitive-dependency

How can I exclude a transitive dependencies just like Maven `exclusions`?

In maven, we often use `exclusions` to exclude them. But I didn't find it in the bazel.

Comment: Please add more details. What language/ruleset are you talking about? Maybe give a concrete example of a case where you want to exclude some dependency.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted optional dependencies in your tree, you would need to model them into the tree using [`select()`](https://bazel.build/reference/be/functions#select) to shape said tree at build time. E.g. instead of:

```
xyz_library(
    name = "libA",
    ...
)

xyz_library(
    name = "libB",
    ...
)

xyz_library(
    name = "intermediate",
    deps = [
        "libA",
        "libB",
    ],
    ...
)

xyz_binary(
    name = "exec",
    deps = [":intermediate"],
    ...
)
```

You the `intermediate` target would looks like:

```
xyz_library(
    name = "intermediate",
    deps = [
        "libA" + select({
            ":condition1": [],
            "//conditions:default": ["libB"],
        }),
    ],
    ...
)
```

To not include the dependency on `libB` when config setting or constraint value `:conditiona1` is matched in the current config. The whole reading on configurable attributes is in the [docs](https://bazel.build/docs/configurable-attributes).

If you wanted to extricate transitive dependency already hard-wired into the tree (e.g. pre-canned 3rd party dep you must take as is and have no control over)... and your specific rule used does not implement such behavior (note: "built-in" things like `cc_binary`, `py_binary`, ... generally do not), you could write a custom rule that could go through values (dependencies) passed through an attribute and process the list incl. disregarding some labels therein as perhaps passed through another attribute.